# Group by value of keys where values can be a list

Tags: python

So I'm trying to group the following object:

```
staffs={
    "James":["basket_ball","swimming"],
    "Cook":"swimming",
    "Peter":"basket_ball",
    "Ben":"coding",
    "Joe":"coding"
}
```

Where the expected output should be:

```
{
    "basket_ball": ["James","Peter"],
    "swimming":["Cook","James"],
    "coding":["Ben", "Joe"]
}
```

Following is what I have done:

```
def group_by_hobby(staffs):
    hobbies = staffs.values()
    obj = {}
    for h in hobbies:
        if(isinstance(h, list)):
            for i in h:
                obj[i] = [k for k in staffs.keys() if staffs[k] == h]
        else:
            obj[h] = [k for k in staffs.keys() if staffs[k] == h]
    print(obj)
```

But the key with the value of list is not being considered. I even added a check if its a list, loop through it and separate the values but doesn't seem to be working. Any idea what I might be missing here?

Apologies for the explanation, still new to Python.

Comment: Your data is not consistant: sometimes you have `list`, sometimes you have `str`. Can you turn your data into de dictionary of lists?

Comment: `if staffs[k] == h` should be `if staffs[k] == i` in the line where you assign `obj[i]`

Comment: What is the actual output?

Comment: Why expect `"swimming":["Cook","James"]`, not `"swimming":["James","Cook"]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each item in the `staffs` dict, you can iterate through hobbies if the value of the dict item is a list, or make it a list by creating a one-item list with it. Use the `dict.setdefault` method to initialize each non-existing dict key with a new list:

```
output = {}
for name, hobbies in staffs.items():
    for hobby in hobbies if isinstance(hobbies, list) else [hobbies]:
        output.setdefault(hobby, []).append(name)
```

`output` becomes:

```
{'basket_ball': ['James', 'Peter'], 'swimming': ['James', 'Cook'], 'coding': ['Ben', 'Joe']}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to be appending to the arrays rather than replacing them in your resulting obj:

```
def group_by_hobby(staffs):
    obj = {}
    for person in staffs.keys():
        hobbies = staffs[person]
        print('hobbies: {}'.format(hobbies))
        if(isinstance(hobbies, list)):
            for hobby in hobbies:
                if hobby not in obj.keys():
                    obj[hobby] = []
                print(hobby)
                obj[hobby].append(person)
        else:
            if hobbies not in obj.keys():
                obj[hobbies] = []
            obj[hobbies].append(person)
    print(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know what hobbies will be present you can simply do:

```py
staffs={
    "James":["basket_ball","swimming"],
    "Cook":["swimming"],
    "Peter":["basket_ball"],
    "Ben":["coding"],
    "Joe":["coding"]
}
hobbies={
    "basket_ball":[],
    "swimming":[],
    "coding":[]
}
for key,value in staffs.items():
    for hobby in value:
        hobbies[hobby].append(key)
print(hobbies)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a function to get the list of hobbies:

```py
def get_hobbies(str_or_list):
    return [str_or_list] if isinstance(str_or_list, str) else str_or_list
```

Then you can use [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to create a dictionary of lists:

```py
result = collections.defaultdict(list)
for name, staff_hobbies in staffs.items():
    for hobby in get_hobbies(staff_hobbies):
        result[hobby].append(name)
```

You get what you want:

```py
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'basket_ball': ['James', 'Peter'], 'swimming': ['James', 'Cook'], 'coding': ['Ben', 'Joe']})
```

Comment: They "need" that function?

Comment: You can use a function to separate concerns, but you can also write it inline in the second "for" loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is, you are again assigning new list to the key even if value for the key was already existing, use this modification to append in list instead of assigning new values

You can use this:

```
def group_by_hobby(staffs):
    hobbies = staffs.values()
    print hobbies
    obj = {}
    for h in hobbies:
        if(isinstance(h, list)):
            for i in h:
                if i not in obj:
                    obj[i] = []
                obj[i] = obj[i]+[k for k in staffs.keys() if staffs[k] == h]
        else:
            if h not in obj:
                obj[h] = []
            obj[h] = obj[h]+[k for k in staffs.keys() if staffs[k] == h]
    print obj
```

Comment: Probably should add a short text what you are missing is - description of why user code not working - and this fixes that.

Comment: given a brief explanation

Answer (score -1):

That's another way to do your job:

```
staffs={
    "James":["basket_ball","swimming"],
    "Cook":"swimming",
    "Peter":"basket_ball",
    "Ben":"coding",
    "Joe":"coding"
}

hobbies = dict()

for x in staffs.values():
    for y in x if isinstance(x, list) else [x]:
        hobbies[y] = []

for x in staffs.keys():
    for y in staffs[x] if isinstance(staffs[x], list) else [staffs[x]]:
        hobbies[y].append(x)

print(hobbies)
```